# In R, discretizing floating point coordinates to nearest coordinate

Tags: r

I am trying to bucket coordinates into their nearest coordinate. In a sense, I am doing one iteration of kmeans clustering, with 1222 centroids. Below I have a function that does this, imperfectly, and too slowly as well. I am looking for help on improving this function:

```
discretizeCourt <- function(x_loc, y_loc) {

  # create the dataframe of points that I want to round coordinates to
  y <- seq(0, 50, by = 2)
  x1 <- seq(1, 93, by = 2)
  x2 <- seq(2, 94, by = 2)
  x <- c(x1, x2)

  coordinates <- data.frame(
    x = rep(x, 13),
    y = rep(y, each = length(x1)),
    count = 0
  )

  # loop over each point in x_loc and y_loc
  # increment the count column whenever a point is 'near' that column      
  for(i in 1:length(x_loc)) {
    this_x = x_loc[i]
    this_y = y_loc[i]

    coordinates[coordinates$x > this_x-1 & 
                coordinates$x < this_x+1 & 
                coordinates$y > this_y-1 & 
                coordinates$y < this_y+1, ]$count =
      coordinates[coordinates$x > this_x-1 & 
                    coordinates$x < this_x+1 & 
                    coordinates$y > this_y-1 & 
                    coordinates$y < this_y+1, ]$count + 1
  }  
}
```

Here is some test data that I'm working with:

```
> dput(head(x_loc, n = 50))
c(13.57165, 13.61702, 13.66478, 13.70833, 13.75272, 13.7946, 
13.83851, 13.86792, 13.8973, 13.93906, 13.98099, 14.02396, 14.06338, 
14.10872, 14.15412, 14.2015, 14.26116, 14.30871, 14.35056, 14.39536, 
14.43964, 14.48442, 14.5324, 14.57675, 14.62267, 14.66972, 14.71443, 
14.75383, 14.79012, 14.82455, 14.85587, 14.87557, 14.90737, 14.9446, 
14.97763, 15.01079, 15.04086, 15.06752, 15.09516, 15.12394, 15.15191, 
15.18061, 15.20413, 15.22896, 15.25411, 15.28108, 15.3077, 15.33578, 
15.36507, 15.39272)

> dput(head(y_loc, n = 50))
c(25.18298, 25.17431, 25.17784, 25.18865, 25.20188, 25.22865, 
25.26254, 25.22778, 25.20162, 25.25191, 25.3044, 25.35787, 25.40347, 
25.46049, 25.5199, 25.57132, 25.6773, 25.69842, 25.73877, 25.78383, 
25.82168, 25.86067, 25.89984, 25.93067, 25.96943, 26.01083, 26.05861, 
26.11965, 26.18428, 26.25347, 26.3352, 26.35756, 26.4682, 26.55412, 
26.63745, 26.72157, 26.80021, 26.8691, 26.93522, 26.98879, 27.03783, 
27.07818, 27.03786, 26.9909, 26.93697, 26.87916, 26.81606, 26.74908, 
26.67815, 26.60898)
```

My actual x_loc and y_loc files are ~60000 coordinates, and I have thousands of files each with ~60000 coordinates, so it's a lot of work. I am pretty certain that the reason the function runs slow is the way I am indexing / incrementing.

The counting is imperfect. A technically better approach would be to loop over all 60000 points (above only 50 points for the example), and for each point, calculate the distance between that point and each point in the coordinates dataframe (1222 points). However thats 60000 * 1222 calculations, just for this one set of points, which is too high.

Would greatly appreciate any help on this!
Thanks,

EDIT: I'm working on converting my dataframes / vectors to 2 matrices, and vectorizing the whole approach, will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process your matrix faster than your solution, consider using `data.table` library. Please see the example below:

```
df <- data.table(x_loc, y_loc) # Your data.frame is turned into a data.table
df$row.idx <- 1:nrow(df) # This column is used as ID for each sample point.
```

Now, we can find the right coordinate for each point. Later we can calculate how many points belong to a certain coordinate. We keep the `coordinates` data frame first:

```
y <- seq(0, 50, by = 2)
x1 <- seq(1, 93, by = 2)
x2 <- seq(2, 94, by = 2)
x <- c(x1, x2)

coordinates <- data.frame(
     x = rep(x, 13),
     y = rep(y, each = length(x1)),
     count = 0
)
coordinates$row <- 1:nrow(coordinates) # Similar to yours. However, this time we are interested in seeing which points belong to this coordinate.
```

Now, we define a function which checks the coordinates and returns the one within one unit distance of the point in question.

```
f <- function(this_x, this_y, coordinates) {
     res <- coordinates[coordinates$x > this_x-1 & 
                             coordinates$x < this_x+1 & 
                             coordinates$y > this_y-1 & 
                             coordinates$y < this_y+1, ]$row
     res
}
```

For each point, we find its right coordinate:

```
df[, coordinate.idx := f(x_loc, y_loc), by = row.idx]
df[, row.idx := NULL]
```

`df` contains the following variables: `(x_loc, y_loc, coordinate.idx)`. You can populate `coordinates$count` using this. Even for 60000 points, it should not take more than 1 second.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(coordinates)) {
    coordinates$count = length(which(df$coordinate.idx == i))
}
```